# Increasing area around plot area in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I increase the area around a plot area in ggplot 2 to give my axis titles some breathing room. I am aware of vjust and hjust (as below), however, I can't seem to create actual space around the plotting area to move my axes titles onto.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p

p<- p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times",size=20,face="bold",colour = "Black",vjust=-1,hjust=0.5)) 
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 98):

Margins around plot can be modified with `theme()`, `plot.margin =`  and function `margin()` where you provide size of margins starting with top, then right, bottom and left, and units (default is "pt").

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times",size = 20,
                face = "bold",colour = "Black",vjust = -1,hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,1,1.5,1.2, "cm"))
```

Comment: The default for `theme_bw()` is now `unit(c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5), "points")`.

Comment: I think grid is no longer needed, I'm using ggplot 2.2.0

Comment: In the case it's helpful to anyone else, here are the arguments to margin (denoting to which side each value corresponds): `margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "pt")`

Comment: Defaults are now: ``margin(half_line, half_line, half_line, half_line)``, where ``half_line <- base_size / 2`` ;-)

Comment: How to add a title?

Comment: I am confused by these comments. The answer does not mention a `margin()` function, so what are the comments that mention `margin()` talking about? Are these intended to imply that using `unit()` is now deprecated?

Comment: @randy Both solutions work but the `margin()` version is newer. I updated the answer.